# Как сгруппировать элементы выборки jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько блоков div:

```
<div class = "one"> </div>
<div class = "two"> </div>

<div class = "three"> </div>
<div class = "four"> </div>

<div class = "five"> </div>
<div class = "six"> </div>
```

Можно ли выбрать сначала первых 2 элементы, потом вторые 2 и т.д. и создать для каждой пары отдельные массивы или аналогично, но с большим количеством элементов?

Comment: код html убрало, вот что я имел в виду:
div1
div2

div3
div4

div5
div6

Comment: нужно сначала собрать собрать всю коллекцию, сделать .toArray и затем splice по 2 элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйде использовать `javascript method` : `slice`.

Функция `slice` получает 2 аргумента: `startIndex`, `endIndex` и возращает под массив.

[Пример](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) использования `slice`.

В случае **если `length` массива четное число** можно сделать так:

```
var $divs = $('div'),
    startIndex = 0,
    resultArr = [];

while(startIndex < $divs.length){
     resultArr.push($divs.slice(startIndex, startIndex  + 2));
     startIndex += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не очень понял, но как-то так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('div'), i, array = [];

  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i += 2){
    var tmp = [];

    tmp.push(els[i]);
    if (els[i + 1] !== undefined)
      tmp.push(els[i + 1]);

    array.push(tmp);
  }

  console.info(array); // Три массива будут в этом массиве - [[div, div], [div, div], [div]]
});
```

```html
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
<div>Item 4</div>
<div>Item 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, как-то так (если я правильно понял) :

```
var divs_el  = document.getElementsByTagName('div');//Получаем div'ы (условно - в конкретном случае div'ы м.б. получены и по другому)
var div2={};//Сюда будем "складывать" пары
var d=0;//Для индесации пар
var i=0;//Счетчик элементов
var i_max = 2;//Каждые 2 элемента
for(e in divs_el){
    if(i==0){div2[d]=[];}//Если новая пара - создаем пременную для ее хранения (м.б. мссив или объект - что удонее)
    div2[d][i]=divs_el[e];//Записываем div в соответствующий массив
    i++;//Увеличиваем i
    if(i>=i_max){i=0; d++;}//Сбрасываем i для нового отсчета, (когда достигло двух) и увеличиваем на 1 d (переходим в след. следующий массив)
}
```

В итоге, получится объект div2, с массивами по 2 div в каждом.
(Все это, конечно, можно записать и покороче. Кроме того, при помощи break и continue, при желании, можно ограичить выборку)